# Out of bounds error..Why?

Tags: c#

AssignCarsAndDrivers has an index out of bounds error, why? I'm doing this for work and the answer seems beyond me.

```
public void Rate()
{
  AssignCarsAndDrivers();
  UnderwritePolicy();
  RateLiability();
}

private void UnderwritePolicy()
{
    if (Policy.Car.ModelYear < 2010)
        throw new ApplicationException("Model year older than 2010.");
}

private void AssignCarsAndDrivers()
{
  if (Policy.Drivers.Count == 0)
    throw new ApplicationException("The policy must have at least one driver.");
  if (Policy.Cars.Count == 0)
    throw new ApplicationException("The policy must have at least one car.");
  for (int driverIndex = 0; driverIndex <= Policy.Drivers.Count; driverIndex++)
  {
    if (
```

Comment: It hard to say without seeing the full code, but should it not be: driverIndex < Policy.Drivers.Count

Comment: `driverIndex` is zero-based, `Policy.Drivers.Count` is not.  The last iteration will break

Comment: a better question is why are you using Exceptions to report simple data validation errors?

Comment: I'm a new developer fresh out of college. I've been here three weeks and they asked the "noobies" to do a small test that they want to start giving during the interview process.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be "less than or equal to (<=)"... Try to change it to "less than (<)", because driverIndex starts from **0**.

Use this:

```
for (int driverIndex = 0; driverIndex < Policy.Drivers.Count; driverIndex++)
```

Instead:

```
for (int driverIndex = 0; driverIndex <= Policy.Drivers.Count; driverIndex++)
```